# javascript variable is not defined error when try to access the value inside the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const roomAndReservationBinding = (rooms, reservations) => {
    var roomInfo = rooms;
    for (var i = 0; i <= roomInfo.length; i++) {
      var room = roomInfo[i];

      console.log(room.id);
    }
  };
```

// on console i get the IDs printed as expected, but on the browser i get the following error, 
room is undefined on the line of console.log() function

Comment: Can you share your input values as well?

Comment: I think the issue is simply that you have <= when it should be just <. If your array has 4 items, your loop will run 5 times (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), on the 5th time it tires to read index 5 from roomInfo, but roomInfo only has 4 items (indexs 0, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: I think the `<=` sign is the root cause. Please replace it with `<`.

Comment: [{id: "77701", dates: Array(31)},
{id: "77702", dates: Array(31)},
{id: "77703", dates: Array(31)}]

Comment: The `<=` sign is the root cause. Please replace it with `<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the root cause -:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= roomInfo.length; i++) {
```

You are iterating one extra time, it should be this -:

```
for (var i = 0; i < roomInfo.length; i++) {
```

```js
  const roomAndReservationBinding = (rooms, reservations) => {
    var roomInfo = rooms;
    for (var i = 0; i < roomInfo.length; i++) {
      var room = roomInfo[i];

      console.log(room.id);
    }
  };
  
  roomAndReservationBinding([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}],[])
```